# Inconsistent execution time

Tags: python, performance, time

I am timing a function I created and getting inconsistent results.  Since I'm using time.time(), I am used to having some small variability in times reported, but my timing data seems bimodal, which I don't understand.

My function:

```
def sorteddups(listA,listB,key=None, equal=lambda x,y:x==y,greater=lambda x,y:x>y,mode=3):#mode: 0=AB, 1=Aonly, 2=Bonly, 3=[Aonly,Bonly,AB]
A=sorted(listA,key=key)
B=sorted(listB,key=key)
AB=[]
dupA=set()
dupB=set()
j=0
for i,a in enumerate(A):
    try:
        while greater(a,B[j]):j+=1
        if equal(a,B[j]):
            AB.append([a,B[j]])
            dupA.add(i)
            dupB.add(j)
    except:pass
if mode==1 or mode==3:Aonly=[a for i,a in enumerate(A) if i not in dupA]
if mode==2 or mode==3:Bonly=[b for i,b in enumerate(B) if i not in dupB]
return AB if mode==0 else Aonly if mode==1 else Bonly if mode==2 else [Aonly,Bonly,AB]
```

My results:

```
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
0.836998701095581
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
1.2330021858215332
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
1.2690012454986572
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
0.8360021114349365
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
1.2589986324310303
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
0.8310055732727051
>>> t=time()
>>> test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
>>> time()-t
1.2420125007629395
```

Any idea what would cause this bimodal distribution of execution time?

Edit: Here's some test code you can run:

```
import random
import string
from time import time
test=[[''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(150)),[random.randint(1,1000) for _ in range(4)],random.random()] for _ in range(200000)]
test2=test
for _ in range(10):
    t=time()
    test3=sorteddups(test,test2)
    print(time()-t)
```

Edit:
I tested this on my machine and my coworkers machine yesterday.  Both produces clearly bimodal results.  Today results are normal for both of us.  My only guess is that there was a system-wide update, but my computer was not restarted.  If anyone has a theory, I'm interested to hear what could cause this on separate machines and then stop the next day on both without a restart.  Marking question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the test and got more consistent results. I would assume that it related to resources of the machine that it runs on.

Result:

```
1.9347724914550781
1.9128038883209229
1.9010097980499268
1.948140277862549
1.9257290363311768
1.9285156726837158
1.9264476299285889
1.9322516918182373
1.9303538799285889
1.931032419204712
```

Comment: What would cause that?  My CPU is sitting at ~5% before I run it each time.  Also, it's much less pronounced in your times, but it still looks like it's a bunch of times at ~.96 and a couple at ~.9.  I'm not surprised when a random run takes longer since I may have caught the system when it was busy, but it's odd to see several runs taking shorter than normal.

Comment: With the new input that you added also pretty same on my machine
 1.9347724914550781
 1.9128038883209229
 1.9010097980499268
 1.948140277862549
 1.9257290363311768
 1.9285156726837158
 1.9264476299285889
 1.9322516918182373
 1.9303538799285889
 1.931032419204712